# jQuery: running setInterval only when a given ID is present

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, I would like to execute this code:

```
setInterval((function() {
  return alert('hello');
}), 3000);
```

but only if the DOM contains a certain element, such as

```
<div id="say_hello">Say hello</div>
```

This must be really basic, but I cannot seem to get it right.

Comment: `if (!!$('#say_hello').length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( $( '#say_hello' ).length > 0 ) {
  setInterval((function() {
    return alert('hello');
  }), 3000);
}
```

Comment: So my question really WAS basic. I got a bunch of identical answers within seconds. I am acccepting this one as it appears first in the list, in hope that the order actually reflects the time of posting. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   if ($('#say_hello').length)    // check for existence of div tag 
   {
        setInterval((function() {
      return alert('hello');
       }), 3000);
   }
});
```